# two digit multiplication (for loops)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
def getProduct(n): 
    product = 1
    while (n != 0): 
        product = product * (n % 10) 
        n = n // 10
    return product 
calc = list()
for number in range(10, 100):
    num = getProduct(number)
    if number == 2 * num:
        calc.append(number)
print(calc)
```

So, the question is to have a column of two digit numbers, which is equal to the (product of the two digits * 2). How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Your question needs to be a bit more refined and detailed. Please edit your question so it's easy to understand what you are trying to do, what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what you mean but im guessing you need code for a two digit calulator

```
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
def getProduct(n): 
    product = 1
    if (n != 0): 
        product = product * (n % 10) * (n//10)
    return product 
calc = list()
for number in range(10, 100):
    num = getProduct(number)
    if number == 2 * num:
        calc.append(number)
print(calc)
```